# Pipelined group by with indexes in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using `PosgtreSQL 9.4` and now I'm trying to understand pipelined `group by`. I created a table consisting of 3 columns (users):

```
------------------------------
|   id   |  name  |   value  |
------------------------------
|   PK   |  text  |  integer |
------------------------------
```

I also created an index on the `name` column as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX users_idx_name
ON users
USING btree(name);
```

I inserted 1 million rows in the table and then I tried to get first 10 aggregated results:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) 
FROM users
GROUP BY name
LIMIT 10;
```

But instead of performing `Index Scan` and `GroupAggregates`, the analyzer returns me the following:

```
Limit  (cost=20403.59..20403.61 rows=2 width=6) (actual time=483.817..483.820 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=20403.59..20403.61 rows=2 width=6) (actual time=483.815..483.817 rows=10 loops=1)
        Group Key: name
        ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..15404.06 rows=999906 width=6) (actual time=0.015..122.012 rows=999906 loops=1)
```

Why? I expected the anallyzer choose `index scan` instead.

Comment: Does it help if you add an ORDER BY clause? http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/example-schema/postgresql/sorting-grouping#apc-pg-ord-group

Comment: It's a tiny table. Plan choices will be different. You need to generate a realistic sized dummy table or use params like `SET enable_seqscan = off` to try to force it to choose plans it thinks are less efficient for the small table.